# Laravel relationship: query with multiple Foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following db schema:

```
    //Pages schema
    Schema::create('pages', function( $table )
        {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('parent_id');
            $table->integer('ordination');
            $table->unsignedInteger('title_id'); //Refer to strings
            $table->unsignedInteger('description_id'); //Refer to strings
            $table->unsignedInteger('url_id'); //Refer to strings



            //Foreign key
            $table->foreign('title_id')->references('id')->on('strings');
            $table->foreign('description_id')->references('id')->on('strings');
            $table->foreign('url_id')->references('id')->on('strings');

        });



    //Strings
    Schema::create('strings', function( $table )
            {

                $table->increments('id');
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->text('en');
                $table->text('de');

            });
```

How I can retrieve a Page Object from the correspondent url string?

I would have a page object or array like the follow:

```
$page['url']['en'] = 'about' 
$page['title']['en']= 'About title'
$page['description']['en']= 'About description'
etc..
```

I can retrieve the page Object from the related url executing the following eloquent query:

```
    $page= Pages::whereHas('url', function( $url )
    {   
        $url->where('en', '=', 'About');

    })->first();
```

With this Eloquent model:

```
 class Pages extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'pages';

    public function url()

        {

            return $this->belongsTo('Strings');

        }
}
```

This will not retrieve the string values for title, description and url, but only their id.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship looks correct. The only thing you need to do is actually load the relation(s). The best way here is eager loading. It will reduce the db queries to a minimum:

```
$pages = Page::with('url')->get();

$page = Page::with('url')->find(1);

$page = Pages::with('url')->whereHas('url', function($url){   
    $url->where('en', '=', 'About');
})->first();
```

To eager load all your string relations simply add them to the `with()` call:

```
$pages = Page::with('url', 'title', 'description')->get();
```